# Connection string setting while deployment

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, connection, mdf

I have ASP.NET project and attached mdf database.I want to deploy it to remote server.I have just ftp account.The project works well on my local but ı had problem while deploying.I changed my connection string like. Please help me what is the problem ?

```
    <add name="libraryConnectionString" 

    connectionString=" Server =.\SQLExpress; 

    AttachDbFilename= myusername@ftp.myserver.com/App_Data/LIBRARY.mdf;

    Integrated Security=SSPI;

    User Instance=True" 

    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You can't just give the FTP path as `AttachedDbFilename` property. You database file must be a local file, accessible for random reads and writes!

Comment: The company gived me just an ftp account and want to deploy my project.I dont know where the project located physically on server.and I have this error

Comment: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file muhammet_evirgen@ftp.veripark.com/App_Data/LIBRARY.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a Ms-Sql server database (remote) along with user via control panel  or you may ask to your hosting provider to create a database and user. Once database is created then you may execute your script (You may use Visual Studio  Database Publishing wizard) and construct a new connection string for your web-app.

Have a look at MSDN article - [Deploying a Database by Using the Database Publishing Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907585.aspx)

> The Database Publishing Wizard in Visual Studio enables you to deploy
>   a SQL Server database (both schema and data) to a hosting environment.
>   You can run the wizard by right-clicking a database in Server Explorer
>   and then clicking Publish to provider.

Comment: I have just an ftp account and ı know the server instance name.I dont know who is the provider of company.

Comment: ı think v 2.0 not support that

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.1 - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5498